# Shopping on Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, tags, closed-questions

I was just told that asking for headphone recommendations is not what AVP is for. I was unaware, and the faq did not tell me otherwise.

Would it be possible to:

1. Remove the [headphone-recommendation] tag
2. Add a link to http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ to the [faq](https://video.stackexchange.com/faq).

Thanks!

Comment: Also: I don't post on the meta much, so please help me out with tags :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question was inappropriate to this site for two reasons: First, it was a shopping question. Rebecca has covered that aspect of it. This is something that applies to all Stack Exchange sites, although some sites allow shopping questions more than others. In all cases, the question should focus on what features to look for, and not ask to be spoonfed a product name.

More importantly in this case, the site is meant to be for audio-video **production**, the recording of sound and video, and *not* the consumption of it. While the site has on occasion answered questions about home setups, it's not the site's main focus and is clearly off-topic here.

Also, the [headphone-recommendation](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headphone-recommendation) tag is valid here, but not for questions about home use. I've submitted an edit to the tag wiki that will explain things a little to future site users.

Comment: Production. Ah, thanks that clears it up. Don't know how I missed that earlier. Oh, and thanks for helping out future site users :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the relevant faq section in this case would be the [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](https://video.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) section.

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

It also links to [this blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) which discusses how to avoid writing open-ended questions.

The page for asking questions also mentions the following, which I think would also discourage recommendations.

> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand. The first quote does not have any applications to shopping questions. In my case, they were practical, answerable, and a problem I faced. It was not open-ended and it was useful. The blog entry is not relevant. The last quote is a restatement of part of the first.

Comment: Your question *is* open-ended and lacks detail.  How do you define "a quality pair of headphones"?  Does your definition match my definition?  You mention a couple options you've already looked at - but you're still asking.  What was wrong with those options?  As it stands, I cannot answer with anything but my opinion on what *I* think is best, and that's not providing a factual answer.

Comment: I don't believe my question lacks detail. Actually, what other detail could I provide? From my question, "a quality pair of headphones" is a pair that would make the music I listen to (given in the question) sound the best. People who are experienced in headphones could give me their diagnosis, and the one with the most helpful answer would be the best answer, like always.

Comment: @Rebecca, you're right in that shopping questions are clearly subjective and unanswerable in the way you and I would think of it. However, to a Stack Exchange newbie, who probably looks at this place as another A/V forum, this isn't immediately obvious. And not every site has the same policy on shopping questions; some *do* allow them, within limits.